# SDL_Window does not name a type

Tags: c++, window, sdl

I'm using GNU/Linux, C++, SDL 1.3
I'm trying to write the code for a "Window" class.

```
#ifndef WINDOW_H
#define WINDOW_H

#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_video.h"
#include "../other/Logger.h"

using namespace std;

class Window {
    public:
        Window(int width, int height, string title);
        ~Window();

    private:
        static const string TAG;
        SDL_Window* window; 
        int width;
        int height;
};

#endif /* WINDOW_H */
```

And when I try to compile I get this error:

```
In file included from Window.cpp:1:0:
Window.h:15:3: error: ‘SDL_Window’ does not name a type.
```

Comment: Do you find the declaration of `SDL_Window` inside `SDL.h`?

Comment: @halex, no. I just tried to follow this example: http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/SDL_CreateWindow#Code_Examples. The thing is, I don't have SDL2.

Comment: @l19 In that case, find a tutorial for SDL 1 or install SDL 2

Comment: @l19 You have to build SDL2 yourself from the sources under http://www.libsdl.org/hg.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SDL_Window` is a datatype from SDL 2.  If you're using SDL 1.x, you need to write your code differently.  See the [Migration Guide](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/MigrationGuide) for more information.